# Is it better to liberate an outpost by going stealth or loud?

Tags: far-cry-4

Is there any advantage or disadvantages in Liberating an Outpost Loud or in Stealth? Just to be clear, I'm not talking about Outpost Master. I'm talking about converting an Enemy outpost.

Is there any XP / Money difference between the two methods? If so what what is the difference, and is there a difference between the South side of the map and North side of the map's outposts?

[image: Map with outpost's icons]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get bonus XP if you do it undetected, the game will tell you with a notification at the top-left. Undetected as in enemies never see you, you can blow them up to kingdom come with the loudest explosives this side of Himalaya and as long as they don't see you you're still okay.

Also, liberating 2 outposts undetected is required to unlock Soft Landing, which is required to unlock Non Stop (unlimited sprinting)

Comment: I was really looking for the difference in XP and Money between the 2 methods.